# Adding a route in Laravel as the last route, from a composer module?

Tags: laravel, laravel-routing

I am making a module for Laravel, and for the ease of reusability, I am making it as a separate composer module.

In this module, I have to define a catch-all route, but I dont want it to override any of the manualy added routes, in the project.

Does anyone have a good idea how I can get this behaviour?

I am registering my route in the ServiceProviders boot() method like this:

```
public function boot()
    {
        $this->loadMigrationsFrom(__DIR__.'/migrations');
        $this->loadRoutesFrom(__DIR__.'/routes/routes.php');
    }
```

and the routes.php is also rather simple:

```
$regex = ".*";

Route::namespace('Asator\\Runepost\\Controllers')
    ->middleware(['web', DynamicContent::class])
    ->group(function($route) use ($regex) {
        $route->any('{any}', 'RunepostFrontController')->where('any', $regex);
    });
```

Is it possible to somehow add the route as the last route, after the manually added routes has run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add your module's ServiceProvider **after** the App's RouteServiceProvider in config/app.php and make sure your catch-all-route is the last route of your module's routes.

Comment: oh yes, that could do it thanks :)
I am using auto-discovery in composer.json, do you know of a way to prioritize how it discopvers it?
Otherwise I will just have to add it manually, it would just be cool if possible :)

Comment: See Taylor's medium post on how to disable autodiscover for particular packages: https://medium.com/@taylorotwell/package-auto-discovery-in-laravel-5-5-ea9e3ab20518